# REST API: extensive filtering/querying a resource (HTTP GET)

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

So, In a rest API (asp.net webapi 2 but the question i'm asking is broader than this alone), what would be the preferred way of providing filtering/querying a resource?

Consider the example resource "/api/company". To have a list of companies, I do a HTTP GET request to "api/company".

Now i want to build some heavy querying possibilities on top of it. Heavy in the sense that I'd like to have the possibility for the user to provide a lot of query fields.

Written as JSON, an example of a query/filter might be, but certainly not limited to:

`[
  {fieldName: 'Name', operator: 'Contains', value: 'blabla'},
  {fieldName: 'InputDate', from: 'some date', to: 'some date'}
  ...
]`

So, more than just some querystring variables appended to the GET request.

Possibilities:

- Use a GET an abuse the body of the request. Not done I guess.
- Use a POST and put the filter in the body. Technically ok, but semantically... mmeeh :) (I AM just asking for results, no updating or creating)
- ... ??

What would be the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: I would use [OData Query Options in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options) in this case

Comment: Honestly, didn't think of oData at all hehe :) Perhaps not the worst idea ;) Thanks

Comment: I met with this question about 3 times in the past few months...

Comment: Well, a link to some of them would be handy in that case ;)